# MagickNET exception when resample PixelCacheAllocationFailed

Tags: c#, .net, magicknet

I use MagickNET in a ASP .NET application. Usually it's works but sometimes with somes files (.jpg, .png) I receive an exception when I resample the picture with another DPI

> ImageMagick.MagickResourceLimitErrorException: iisexpress.exe: PixelCacheAllocationFailed `D:\Data\IT Tools and Applications\Code\Zola\ZolaIntranet\Upload\Temp\4ffe031b-b559-4b5c-8f88-e1a5b8e4fbe7.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3369

Here the line where the exception happens :

```
 tmpImage.Resample(new PointD(300,300));
```

When I tried to use a smaller DPI (72 or less) I got another exception :

> ImageMagick.MagickCacheErrorException: iisexpress.exe: UnableToExtendCache 'D:\Data\IT Tools and Applications\Code\Zola\ZolaIntranet\Upload\Temp\42458df9-f7ee-4e4b-abfd-628317b4b7eb.jpg': Invalid argument @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3536 ---> ImageMagick.MagickCacheErrorException: iisexpress.exe: UnableToExtendCache

Can someone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you share that image? Feel free to contact me on CodePlex if you don't want to do that publicly.

Comment: Hi diemstra. Sure, here the picture http://postimg.org/image/wpv7rh0kh/ What I remarked, when I tried to open this same picture with Gimp, I had also a message : ... this image has a color profil... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with the latest development build could you give that a try? Instructions are on https://magick.codeplex.com

Comment: I'm already on the last version (7.0.0.22), Q8 package and with .NET 4.5 and I had some strange problem with the png format files. The previous problem it's not solved and the problem come from the same function : resample(). Sometimes it even doesn't give me any error but it continue to work with no result. Other functions like the write() or crop() (png to jpg) works nice and quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one or another reason, for few pictures in PNG format ImageMagick cant't find the density of the picture. You have to specify a density before calling `Resample()` function and that resolve my problem.

```
PointD density = new PointD(300,300);

tmpImage.Density = density;
tmpImage.Resample(density);
tmpImage.Write(image);
```